# Wait for render to complete before changing DOM

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I ran into the situation where a simple placeholder should be replaced by another component which is waiting for asychronous data. As the data is available, the dependant component is being rendered. Imagine a loading spinner / skeleton which is then replaced by a list of users, for example.

The problem is, that the placeholder should be replaced within 1 frame, so that the overall height of the component is continuously preserved. This is not the case, since the rendering takes some time, which results in a bouncing effect.

The following snippet is given as an simplified example:

```
render() {
    {dataAvailable ? renderPlaceholder : renderDeepComponentTree}
}
```

The replacement takes between 50-150ms in my certain case, which makes the page-height bounce.

Any solution to this?

Comment: can you set the height to a fixed value and then re-render when the data becomes available? That way, the page height wouldn't change.

Comment: absolute position the `renderPlacholder`?

Comment: the placeholder has the same height. the problem is, that the `DeepComponentTree` takes some time to render and the height goes down to zero, until the rendering has finished